# Physics Raycasting In Untiy

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I've set up a Physics Raycast Event System for the Google Cardboard in Unity, which works if I use a cube or any of the pre-set 3D objects. When I import my own object from 3DS Max, however, the Raycast doesn't seem to detect the object. I've checked, my object does have a collider on it, and the layer is set at default. I'm using the GVR API, and the GVR Reticle Pointer.

[image: The object which is being detected]

[image: The object which isn't being detected]

Comment: Not sufficient to help you. You need to post that code and screenshot of the imported GameObject in the Inspector tab. This will show what's attached to it and what's not.

Comment: Added new information!

Comment: You are using different script. Why not use the-same Cube script you used too and see what happens.

Comment: I'm using the same script, i.e. Select Part in both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Collider is not even aligned on that imported Object. The center value of the Collider should be *0*,*0*,*0* so reset that. After that, click the *"Edit Collider"* button, go to the Scene View and modify the Collider until it matches the shape/size of your imported 3D model.

See the image I am talking about below for more info:

[image]

Comment: I did this, but even after all these changes, the GVR Pointer still isn't picking the wall up

Comment: Running out of ideas. Do you have a scripti called "Basic Wall"?

Comment: Nope. Neither of the objects have custom scripts on them.

Comment: If you can upload the project somewhere and share the link here, I will take a look at it

Comment: Got the project. How do I replicate issue?

Comment: If you run the VR application, you'll see a log everytime you click on the cube. The same log will not work when you try and click on the house! That's my issue. I guess this means that the RayCast isnt hitting the collider on the house, I just don't know why